# Как дождаться загрузки BitmapImage?

Tags: c#, .net

Есть `BitmapImage` и у него есть проблема. Его нельзя просто создать. Можно только начать его инициализацию, после чего он сгенерирует события, типа `DownloadCompleted` или `DownloadFailed`. А мне необходимо сделать так, чтобы метод, в котором он инициализируется не возвращал ничего, пока инициализация не прошла. Но как? Не ставить же цикл `while`.

Answer (score 0):

Например, так:

```
var bi = new BitmapImage();
bi.BeginInit();
bi.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
bi.UriSource = ...;
bi.EndInit();
// если передаёте в другой поток, ещё нужно
bi.Freeze();
```

Поскольку загрузка может быть медленной, я бы рекомендовал вынести в фоновый поток через `Task.Run`:

```
BitmapImage image = await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        var bi = new BitmapImage();
        // ...
        return bi;
    });
```